# The cover of my passport had deattached from the old passport. I am under F1 status in the US. can I still travel with it?

Tags: visas, study, customs-and-immigration

The cover of my passport had deattached from the old passport. I am under F1 status in the US. It happened at a layover and when the immigration officer checked he didn't say anything. Can I still travel with it?

Comment: old passport? is it not your current passport?